# Establish ssh session by giving password using script in python

Tags: python, ssh

I have written a below script to do **ssh** and providing password .But it still waits for password prompt while running . Searched through many such questions on stack overflow, Everyone suggesting to use paramiko or pexpect but I can not use this as this script has to be run by many people on different machines and can not ask everyone to install these libraries first

Looking for a solution without using such libraries

```
import subprocess
import sys 

HOST="lab@xxxx"
COMMAND="pwd"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

ssh.stdin.write('lab\n')
ssh.stdin.flush()
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []: 
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

~

Comment: I suggest you use pem files for authentication as using ssh with password, especially with the raw characters of the password in a script.